# How to increase the font size of the bounding box in Tensorflow object detection module?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have increased the font size to 30 from the default size 24 inside the draw_bounding_box_on_image() in visualization_utils.py

font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 30)

But still the font size is not getting changed.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the change is not just hidden by pixel quantization or something ? If you use 60 instead, is it still the same size (it works fine for me) ? And on my version at least there is   `try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 24)
  except IOError:
    font = ImageFont.load_default()`, are you sure you're not falling in the IOError case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i found the issue.
On Mac we need to give the full path.
ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 30)
```

Also, we can put the .ttf file in the current folder and use

```
 ImageFont.truetype('./Arial.ttf', 30)
```

Comment: For me works only `ImageFont.truetype('./Arial.ttf', 30)`

Comment: For Ubuntu see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50006012/3458744

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu OS, I did the following

```
    import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
...
  try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fm.findfont(fm.FontProperties(family='DejaVu Sans')), 50)
  except IOError:
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
```

and it worked :)
PS. I suppose that it will work for any OS.