# Customizing TF Object Detection bounding box thickness & label font size

Tags: tensorflow, fonts, object-detection, label, bounding-box

Running predictions with https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb.

- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:

  > Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Would like to customize label font size & bounding box thickness as my label text & bbox are too thick in image detections.

### [image: Cannot see detections!]

Thank you for any help! If you have done this yourself please pass along your learnings! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can change the bounding boxes thickness by changing the `line_thickness` parameter in the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`as follows:

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
```

Comment: for some reasons any change of line_thickness, even if directly changed in the draw_ functions does NOT show any effect? What am I missing

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

To change font size:

In file `models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py`
starting from line 202:

Try:

```
  font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 24) 
except IOError:
  font = ImageFont.load_default()
```

Here we just need to change number 24 to desired font size.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 16.04 seemingly does not ship with the `arial.ttf` font  - and this is unfortunately what `vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` uses by default and it is not configurable except by changing the python code. When it can't find that font it uses a default bitmap font, however the resolution is too low for many purposes, especially at low DPI settings.

However you can workaround this problem in a number of ways:

- Install the Microsoft core fonts with: `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (this however did not work for me - not sure why)
- Or copy the very similar font `DejaVuSans.ttf` to a file with the name `arial.ttf` in the directory `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu`
- Or copy `DejaVuSans.ttf` to a file with the name `arial.ttf` in your `object_detection` directory (assuming you are running your code there)

Then you can visualize your boxes and labels with `DPI=100` and still read the font.

Before - 100 DPI with the default bitmap font:

[image]

After - 100 DPI with `arial.ttf`

[image]

Comment: Where do we put the `DPI=100`?

Comment: It has been awhile and I don't have the code in front of me, but I suspect the command that saves to a jpg.